# How to assign value to a list or vector object inside a vector in R

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I have a list like

```
mylist = list('a','b','c','d')
```

and another vector inside which I wish to call mylist object to assign a value.

```
myvec = c('p'=0,'q'=1, mylist[1]=1)
```

But executing it gives error

```
Error: Unexpected '=' in "c('p'=0,'q'=1, mylist[1]="
```

I have used python before where such assignment is possible and straight forward. But same doesn't work in R. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setNames()`, also note that *mylist[1]* gives a one element list, in order to get the element at position one, you need to use *[[* (which doesn't seem to matter in this case, i.e, both works):

```
c('p' = 0,'q' = 1, setNames(1, mylist[[1]]))

#p q a 
#0 1 1
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked. Can you give a little explanation on why its so indirect in R while pretty straight forward in Python ?

Comment: @Ashutosh I think you can do that in python only with dictionary not with list, in which case, it is probably because it has a special `:` instead of `=` expression which can give extra complexity in this case.